# Why does ${\lambda _i}(A) \ge {\lambda _i}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_n}$ are Hermitian and $A-B$ has only nonnegative eigenvalues.Why does ${\lambda _i}(A) \ge {\lambda _i}(B)$  (for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$) ?

Comment: If they are simultaneously diagonalizable, then this is pretty much obvious. Otherwise I am not so sure. Maybe try $A$ diagonal and $B$ having eigenvector matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ for intuition?

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the Monotonicity Theorem, which says that if $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and $B$ is positive semi-definite, then
$$\lambda_i(A+B) \ge \lambda_i(A).$$

Indeed, the Montonicity Theorem itself is a consequence of [Weyl's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality), which says if $A,B$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian, then
$$\lambda_i(A) + \lambda_1(B) \ge \lambda_i(A+B) \ge \lambda_i(A) + \lambda_n(B).$$
We can see that $B$ being positive semi-definite means that $\lambda_n(B) \ge 0$ so that the monotonicity theorem follows immediately from Weyl's inequalities.

For your result, we simply apply the monotonicity theorem to $B$ and $A-B$ (which is positive semi-definite) to get
$$\lambda_i(A) = \lambda_i(B + (A-B)) \ge \lambda_i(B).$$

Comment: solid fukin answer B, upvotes to the left